# How to properly instantiate function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have this method inside my class

```
class Manager{

...

template<typename V, typename T>
void checkAllDistance(const V& vectorList, T& applianceType, const Vec2& point);

...

}
```

I have it defined in my header and it works perfectly fine. However, I get his message when I compile my code

```
1>Manager.cpp(120): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Manager::checkAllDistance<cocos2d::Vector<Pat *>,Pat*>(const V &,T &,const cocos2d::Vec2 &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            V=cocos2d::Vector<Pat *>,
1>            T=Pat *
1>        ]
```

In that line I have

```
checkAllDistance(pat_holder, temp_pat, point);
```

Like I said, it compiles and works fine, but I'd like to know how to properly instantiate it.

Comment: What's the full compiler output?

Comment: That was all the message I got related to it.

Comment: @DanielSega Then post the messages you think are unrelated.  That message is a note relating to some other message.

Comment: There should be a line preceding the note in the output.

Comment: The only other message, again it compiles and run perfectly fine
    1>Manager.h(167): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch (compiling source file Manager.cpp)

Comment: If that message is the one that immediately precedes the output in the question, then the note is for that warning.

Comment: @Bernard, you were right. I changed my size_t to int and that note disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The VC++ compiler produces output lines that start with `note:` to report additional information about the error/warning immediately preceding the note.  The note is not an error/warning by itself, but may be helpful in understanding the preceding error/warning, usually by stating the the name and location of the containing function where the error/warning is produced.

Simply fix the preceding error/warning, and the note will not be produced when compiling again.